# Possible different combinations of two digits in C language

Tags: c, integer

I want to write a program that prints the possible combinations of two digits, where the output prints the smallest combination of two digits (eg: 34, 43 are combinations of two digits and are considered the same combination of digits, but only 34, the smaller value gets printed), must be in ascending order and the two digits must be different.

Also, I'm not to use printf, but putchar,
Values 0 - 9

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    for (a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {
        for (b = 0; b < 10; b++)
        {
            printf("%d", a);
            printf("%d", b);
            putchar(',');
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return (0);
}
```

This is all I know and what I've tried. I'm just two days into C, so please... Thanks

Comment: I recommend you step away from the computer, and instead get a pen and some paper. Then spend a few hours to try and figure out a way to not display (perhaps not even loop over) the larger combinations.

Comment: I've been thinking about it, trying to see how to use if statements to achieve that. But I dunno if it'll work. But I'll leave the computer as you said and see if I can come up with a solution

Comment: I suggest that you try to solve this problem first by hand, on pen&paper, without the help of a computer program. Write all digit combinations that you want to output onto pen&paper, and try to find a systematic approach of doing so. Once you have found the algorithm on pen&paper, you can then think about how to implement this algorithm in a computer program.

Comment: It's a small thing, but `printf("%d%d,", a, b);`

Comment: `putchar(a + '0');` will output a single digit, provided that `a` is between 0 and 9.

Comment: `for (b = 0; b < 10; b++)` --> `for (b = a + 1; b < 10; b++)`